# mappedBy doesn't work with Inheritance in hibernate. Any workaround?

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa

Consider the following three classes

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "GenericIdGenerator",
sequenceName = "GENERIC_SEQ", initialValue = 1)
@Table(name = "tbl_datastores")
public abstract class DataStore implements Serializable {

    private int storeId;

    public getStoreId()
    {
        return this.storeId;
    }

    //..other code removed for brevity.
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_filedatastores")
public class FileDataStore extends DataStore {

    private Set<FieldDetails> fields;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="datastore")
    public getFields()
    {
        return this.fields;
    }
    //..other code removed for brevity.
}

@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_fields")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "GenericIdGenerator",
sequenceName = "GENERIC_SEQ", initialValue = 1)
public class FieldDetails
{
    private int fieldId;
    private DataStore datastore;

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="GenericIdGenerator")
    @Column(name="id", nullable=false, updatable=false)
    public int getFieldId() {
        return fieldId;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name="datastore_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    public FileDataStore getDataStore(){
        return datastore;
    }
    //..other code removed for brevity.
}
```

When I run this code I get the following error...

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity  property: entities.FieldDetails.datastore in entities.FileDataStore.fields
```

I have seen some [posts](http://chriswongdevblog.blogspot.com/2009/10/polymorphic-one-to-many-relationships.html) that seem to suggest it is a hibernate issue but I could not get a proper solution anywhere?

Can you please suggest a way to map this in hibernate or a workaround?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the difference in character case in property names. It should be either

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="dataStore") 
...
public FileDataStore getDataStore(){ ... }
```

or

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="datastore") 
...
public FileDataStore getDatastore(){ ... }
```

Comment: Thank you axtavt!! That worked!That was kind of silly for me not to spot that.